# Skipping import modules in pytest from the command line

Tags: python, import, pytest

The documentation for `pytest` suggests you can skip certain imports:

https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/skipping.html#skipping-on-a-missing-import-dependency

We are trying to run pylint under pytest and in some cases importing `tensorflow` causes issues because of system dependencies. The documentation shows a way of skipping the import in code, is it possible to skip imports like this from the command line of `pytest`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such feature in `pytest`, so you should do this directly in code (usually in a `conftest.py`).

A hacky workaround to do the same directly at the command line woud be:

```
python -c "import pytest; pytest.importorskip('tensorflow'); pytest.main()"
```

Better would be to use one of the existing [hooks](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/_modules/_pytest/hookspec.html) to add your own command-line option to pytest, so it can be specified clearly like `--no-tensorflow` or whatever.